# How to make uwsgi shut down if application failed to load?

Tags: python, deployment, uwsgi

I run my uwsgi in the simplest way possible, as a process managed by upstart, no emperor mode or anything. This is what I get if application fails on startup for some reason:

```
[traceback skipped]
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17923)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17948, cores: 1)
...
```

I have no use for this mode, and would like it to shut down completely, so my upstart job shows as stopped.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The option

--need-app

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your Uwsgi server through .ini file, add the below arg:

`need-app = true`

This will start the server only if the app is running fine.